# c3.js - How can I set the y lines value to the first value from url (json data)

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

How can I set the y lines value to the first value from URL? (JSON data)

```
var chartDisplay = c3.generate({
    bindto: '.chart',
    data: {
        url: '/stats',
        mimeType: 'json',
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [ {
                value: data1  <---- this is what I cant figure out
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

The json data looks like this:

```
{
  "data1": 3000, 
  "data2": [
    3000, 
    3300.0, 
    3410.0, 
    4520.0,
  ]
}
```

Comment: in your grid-setting you want a reference to your json. since you load your json via request instead of having it locally i don't think you can do this. if you would have your json loaded beforehand you could do `value: myjson.data1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this to your chart declaration,

```
    onrendered: function () {
        this.api.ygrids([
          {value: this.data.targets[0].values[0].value, text:'data 1 value'},
        ]);
    },
```

this.api is basically the same as the 'chart' variable, and this.data is a pointer to the loaded dataset. `targets[0]` will be the first series loaded (data1) and `values[0].value` will be the value of the first entry

http://jsfiddle.net/y7axwubf/1/

Comment: Fantastic!! This did exactly what I wanted,  thank you for your help